# Bat file does not run via task scheduler on server

Tags: batch-file, cmd, copy

I have a very simple bat script which copies files from a mapped network drive to my SharePoint environment (a document library mapped to the machine via web dav).

copy y:* z:\

This works without any issues when running directly from the cmd but from the task scheduler.

The task is set not to store password
Also set to run with highest privileges
Set to run for Server 2012 R2 (my OS)

The action is the script file and start in is the path of the file.

What is missing?

Comment: `y:*` is a relative path; it that what you want? to refer to the files in the root directory of drive `y:`, state `y:\*` instead (note the backslash)...

Comment: Mapped drives are done by security token. Admins have two tokens, limited and full admin. You have to map in the one you want to use. Or `copy \\server1\share\folder\file.ext \\server2\share\folder\file.ext`.